# Run multiple commands in plink.exe

Tags: batch-file, aix, plink

I need to run multiple commands in a remote AIX server using `plink.exe` with a batch file.

I currently have the batch file like this:

```
plink.exe -pw pass user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cd /home/data/test
rm logs/*%1.*
rm Imp_%1.log
sqlplus user/pass @do_stuff.sql 001 %1 YES
sh do_stuff.sh %1
```

When i run it the following error is returned:

> "A file or directory in the path name does not exist"

When I try the above lines in a command prompt they run without problem.

What is the best way to run all the commands?

Comment: The line separator on AIX is the semi-colon. So you probably need `PLINK ... "command1; command2; command3"`

Comment: Or `plink.exe -pw pass user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <commands.txt` where `commands.txt` contains the commands you'd normally run at the plink prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now the batch run but how i put the variable in the txt file?

Comment: Create a shell script on the remote server and run that with plink.exe Or create the script on the client, transfer it to the server (pscp), and run that with plink.exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute multiple commands sequentially on device in Windows batch file using PuTTY/Plink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170536/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-sequentially-on-device-in-windows-batch-file-us)